# NetBSD - no pkg

Tags: installation, netbsd

After full installation of latest NetBSD I'm tried to launch `pkgin`, but received `pkgin not found`, also I've got same for `pkgsrc`. Then I've found, that there's no `/usr/pkg` location.

That's normal or I've did something wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-pkgin-on-netbsd-6/

Comment: Interesting one, but I have no internet connection on target machine. 
It comes with TP-Link WLAN dongle, but I can't set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pkgin` and `pkgsrc` are not part of a default NetBSD install.

From [pkgin.net](http://pkgin.net/):  *Pkgin is available via github, or pkgsrc-wip, and is present in pkgsrc as pkgtools/pkgin.*

[pkgsrc](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/stable/pkgsrc.tar.gz) is a separate source archive that can be extracted (unpacked) on a development system and then used to fetch, build, and install third-party software packages, and also to build binary packages for installation on a non-development system.

pkgin requires either a network connection, or a directly accessible directory containing a binary package repository.

Using pkgsrc to build packages also requires either a network connection, or a directly accessible directory containing the original source distribution archives for those packages you might wish to install.

In your case, since you don't have a working network interface on your target machine, what you will probably have to do is burn a DVD (or CD-ROM, or use some other form of attachable disk that you can create on a network-connected NetBSD system) with copies of the binary packages you wish to install and then mount it on your target machine.

You can get pre-built binary packages for NetBSD itself from:

ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/i386/6.0/All

You can then install them with `pkg_add` directly , or you can just install the `pkgin` package itself and then follow the instructions on [the pkgin web site](http://pkgin.net/#usage) to use `pkgin` to install the other packages you need, giving your DVD mount point as your package repository.

Answer (score 0):

To install pkgin and git on NetBSD 8.1:

$ export PKG_PATH="http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/amd64/8.1/All/"

$ su

# echo $PKG_PATH

# pkg_add -v pkgin

# pkg_add -v git

# exit

$ git